# Inconsistent result from basic lstlisting

Tags: listings

Is it possible to understand why, and fix the faulty highlighting (inconsistent bold of only a few) in the listlistings for bash? The default rendering is worse than random. There is no reason why cd is bold and rm is not.

[image]

```
\begin{lstlisting}[
 basicstyle=\normalsize, language=Bash, showstringspaces=false, label={bashge2}, breaklines, caption=demo.sh
]
sudo ./compromise.sh # install a compromised tcc
cd /tmp
rm -rf tcctmp
\end{lstlisting}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: I agree that it looks poor, but _technically_ I think `sudo` and `rm` are separate programs and not `bash` commands, which is why I guess the `bash` language definition leaves them out.  You can see what *is* included in the docs here:  https://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings, and it is really easy to add your own.

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to improve it -- add some missing keywords, use some colour, and put it all in mono font.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{listings}
\RequirePackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{textblue}{rgb}{.2,.2,.7}
\definecolor{textred}{rgb}{0.54,0,0}
\newcommand\basher{\lstset{
language=Bash,
basicstyle=\ttfamily,
keywordstyle=\color{textblue},
commentstyle=\color{textred},
frame=none,
columns=fullflexible,
keepspaces=true,
xleftmargin=\parindent,
showstringspaces=false,
morekeywords={rm, sudo}
}}
\lstnewenvironment{shell}[1][]{\basher\lstset{#1}}{}
\begin{document}
\begin{shell}
sudo ./compromise.sh # install a compromised tcc
cd /tmp
rm -rf tcctmp
\end{shell}
\end{document}
```

which should produce something like this:

[image]

The optional argument I have added to my suggested `shell` environment allows you to put the caption and label in like this:

```
\begin{shell}[caption=demo.sh, label={bashge2}]
sudo ./compromise.sh # install a compromised tcc
cd /tmp
rm -rf tcctmp
\end{shell}
```